# Using let variable in query of $geoNear stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections:

`users` collection:

```py
{
    "_id" : "f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa7",
    "email" : "a8bbac28-a56c-11ea-b9c0-0242ac120003@gmail.com",
    "password" : "12345678",
    "is_active" : true,
}
```

and `locations` collection:

```py
{
    "_id" :"5ed75285ed832773ca2a7b1e",
    "user_id" : "f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa7",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            105.785076,
            20.978734
        ]
    },
   "radius": 10000
}
```

Now I want to filter active user, then calculate distance between locations of filtered user with a specific location:

```py
db.users.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "is_active": true,
    },
    {
        "$group": {
           "_id": null,
            "userIds": {
                "$addToSet": "$_id"
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "locations",
            "as": "locations",
            "let": {"userIds": "$userIds"},
            "pipeline": [
                {
                "$geoNear": {
                        "near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 105.843111, 21.045752 ]},
                        "distanceField": "distance",
                        "query": {
                            "user_id": {"$in": "$$userIds"}    <-- this line cause ERROR
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$redact": {
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": {"$lte": ["$distance", "$radius"]},
                            "then": "$$KEEP",
                            "else": "$$PRUNE",
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],
        }
    }
])
```

I recieved error:

```py
{
    "message" : "Failed to determine whether query system can provide a covered projection :: caused by :: $in needs an array",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

When I remove `$lookup` stage and show result, `userIds` is an array.

My expected output:

```py
{
    _id: null,
    "userIds": [
        f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa7,
        f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa4,
        f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa1,
        f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa6
    ],
    "locations": [
        {
            "_id" :"5ed75285ed832773ca2a7b1e",
            "user_id" : "f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa7",
            "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                    105.785076,
                    20.978734
                ]
            },
        "radius": 10000.
        "distance": 5
        },
        {
            "_id" :"5ed75285ed832773ca2a7b1e",
            "user_id" : "f494509018d3487c8acbcdc5c7508aa7",
            "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                    105.785076,
                    20.978734
                ]
            },
        "radius": 10000,
        "distance": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone know about this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: @ngShravil.py can you explain more detail, where is wrong ? Thanks

Comment: @ngShravil.py so Is there any way to pass `userIds` from `$group` stage to `$geoNear` in `$lookup` stage

Comment: It's not effective here. I am wanting to pass `userIds` that I have created in `$group` stage to `$lookup` stage. If I change the name to `user_Ids` then in `lookup`, `let` statement become `"let": {"userIds": "$user_Ids"}`. But the error still happend

Comment: @ngShravil.py, I added the expected output in the question. Pls, review it

Comment: What is `owner`, is it a field? And you are using `$in` operator in wrong way.

Comment: Oh sr, it's not `onwer`, it's `user_id`, I fixed the question. I am using `$in` as docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/ :  `{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }` . And `$in` operator is using in wrong way ? You mean `$in` in aggregate: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/, like this: `{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }`

Comment: Yes.. the aggregation one..

Comment: as docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/, `query` is read syntax, so I have to use query one. If using the aggregation one, I have to create one more stage in pipeline of `$lookup`, right?

Comment: Any solution for this one?
I have similar problem. I need to use variables from the let stage into geoNear's near parameter
`near: { "type": "Point", "coordinates":["$$letlon", "$$letlat"]}`